# include panel-specific trends in a first-difference regression

Tags: stata

I was wondering if there's a way to include panel-specific or just varying trends in a first-difference regression when clustering on the panel id and the time variable.

Here's an example of with Stata:

```
. webuse nlswork
(National Longitudinal Survey.  Young Women 14-26 years of age in 1968)

. ivreg2 S1.(ln_wage tenure) , cluster(idcode year)

OLS estimation
--------------

Estimates efficient for homoskedasticity only
Statistics robust to heteroskedasticity and clustering on idcode and year

Number of clusters (idcode) =     3660                Number of obs =    10528
Number of clusters (year) =          8                F(  1,     7) =     2.81
                                                      Prob > F      =   0.1378
Total (centered) SS     =  1004.098948                Centered R2   =   0.0007
Total (uncentered) SS   =  1035.845686                Uncentered R2 =   0.0314
Residual SS             =   1003.36326                Root MSE      =    .3087

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
   S.ln_wage |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      tenure |
         S1. |   .0076418   .0042666     1.79   0.073    -.0007206    .0160043
             |
       _cons |   .0501738   .0070986     7.07   0.000     .0362608    .0640868
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Included instruments: S.tenure
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. ivreg2 S1.(ln_wage tenure i.c_city), cluster(idcode year)
factor variables not allowed
r(101);
```

In the specification above, the constant corresponds to a common time trend. Putting the factor variable outside the seasonal difference operator errors as well.

I understand that the differencing operator does not play well with factor variables or interactions, but I feel there must be some hack to get around that.

The `ivreg2` is a bit of a red herring. I am not doing IV estimation, I just want to use two-way clustering.

Comment: Other than creating dummies and using these as regressors (which is of course tedious if you have many), I don't see alternative options. However, this is not a big deal (with dummies)if you are using these outside the seasonal difference operators.  For example: `tabulate   ind_code, gen(ind);  ivreg2 S1.(ln_wage tenure) ind2-ind12, cluster(idcode year)` should work if you want these outside.

Answer (score 0):

You get the same solution as @Metrics if you do `xi: ivreg2 S1.(ln_wage tenure) i.ind_code , cluster(idcode year)`